# How can I copy and edit a file in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

This seems so simple but I can't find a good way to do it:

Often I want to take an existing (Java) file and base a new one on it - basically just copy the file, rename the copy, and edit it.  I can't find any good way to do this.  The best I can do is to right-click on the file in the Package Explorer, select copy, and then paste it.  If I do it in the same directory I'm prompted to change its name, which is cool.

The problems with this are: 1) It doesn't seem very "Eclipse-y", and 2) Usually I don't have the Package Explorer expanded to where the source file is, so it's very tedious to go through all the projects/packages and find it.

There must be a better way to do this, no?  I expected something in the refactor menu but all there is is "move".

Alternative is there a simple way to show where a file I'm currently editing is in the Package Explorer?  That wouldn't be ideal but would be good enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the top right portion of the package explorer, there is a "link with editor" button that will automatically highlight which file you have open in the editor.

Comment: And then there is Ctrl + C and Ctrl + V so one doesn't have to fiddle with the right click context menu.

Comment: Thank you - I'm going to accept your answer just because it has fewer clicks (but really I wish I could accept both).

Answer (score 1):

Select 'Show In - Package Explorer' in the context menu of your editor.

Comment: I knew it would be something simple like this!  Thank you.